# why does a4j:poll just work one time when I use it in my jsf page which is ui:defined with a template .xhtml

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I create a template xhtml file which is like richfaces-showcase main.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 8 -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"  />
        <title>My title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="page">
            <ui:insert name="body">
                Body content missed
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

And in sub page, I defined the "template body", and add an a4j:poll in my sub page, which I want to use to refresh the data every 5 seconds:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<ui:composition template="/templates/main.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form>
            <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="5000" enabled="true" action="..." render="poll,grid" />
        </h:form>        

        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="80%" id="grid">
                 sorry, details forgot ...
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

But the question is, when I open my sub page with IE8 in the localhost computer, the a4j:poll can refresh data once, and then it never get data again. when I open the sub page with IE6 or IE8 in other computer, it works fine! Can anybody find the reason out? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I change the

```
<h:head>
    <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 8 -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"  />
    <title>My title</title>
</h:head>
```

to

```
<h:head>
    <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 7 -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"  />
    <title>My title</title>
</h:head>
```

and, it works now... but why?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with EmulateIE8. But probably when using it in an intranet way IE can be doing things differently.

Check your Browser mode and Document mode (press <kbd>F12</kbd>).

I got: IE9 / IE8 standards.